# Mover un elemento html presionando una tecla desde js

Tags: javascript, html

estoy aprendiendo programación y me he prepuesto hacer el juego de la serpiente y estoy haciendo que al presionar w se mueve en una dirección pero no consigo que haga nada no se en donde me estoy equivocando.

```
cabeza.addEventListener("keydown", function moverse(){
    const recto = Event.key;
    console.log("FUNCIONAAAAA1")
    if(recto === "w"){
        do{
            cabeza.style.left = "100px";
            cabeza.style.left = "100px";
            console.log("FUNCIONAAAAA")
        }
        while(cabeza.addEventListener("keyup"));
    }
});
```

el console.log es para saber donde se queda la función ejecutada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo muy básico, mejorable, pero funcional.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <span id="cabeza">*</span>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS (archivo styles.css)

```
#contenedor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}

#cabeza {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript (archivo app.js)

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", moverCabeza);
const cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");

function moverCabeza(e) {
  let horizontalValue = getComputedStyle(cabeza, null)
    .getPropertyValue("left")
    .slice(0, -2);
  horizontalValue = Number(horizontalValue);

  if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    cabeza.style.left = horizontalValue + 10 + "px";
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    cabeza.style.left = horizontalValue - 10 + "px";
  }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que cuando detectas el evento key, generalmente no lo haces sobre un elemento específico ej: "cabeza", generalmente lo haces sobre una caja de texto o directamente a algo mas global, como el document, de esa forma sin importar el foco, si está el sitio abierto capturará el evento key que desees.

En este ejemplo hice todo para izquierda y derecha, tendrías que hacerte una let verticalValue con todo igual a horizontal pero sacando el valor de top en vez de left. Luego las funciones son iguales, solo cambia la key que recibis en la condición y el eje que usaras para el movimiento vertical

Comment: soy nuevo en esto, la e en la función movercabeza es para llamar toda la función en el if puede ser?, para asi solo escribir "e".                                                       
 igualmente gracias por la respuesta me has ayudado

Comment: La "e" que recibe la función "moverCabeza", es el evento que se genera al presionar una tecla, esto es un parámetro, puede llevar cualquier nombre, generalmente se utiliza "e", o "ev", o "event". Luego dentro del objeto que devuelve el evento, se pueden obtener data de ese evento. Nosotros usamos el "e.key" que devuelve el nombre de la tecla presionada y en función de eso hacemos una cosa u otra. Favor no olvides dar la respuesta como solución dando click al visto al costado de la respuesta y votar hacia arriba si es posible. Si consideras que fue la solución. Gracias!

Comment: okey gracias por la explicación sobre que es la  "e"

Answer (score 0):

Yo estoy combinando canvas con estos eventos de teclas para hacer mover una imágen en el canvas y que parezca que se mueve un personaje de un juego, como tu quieres mover la culebra, yo lo hice algo así...

 HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="viewMap">
       <h1>Traverse the Map with your Mokepon</h1>
       <canvas id="map"></canvas>
    </section>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
const map = document.getElementById('map')
let canvas2D = map.getContext("2d")

function startGame(){
//...
//Chequea todas las teclas presionadas en el documento o sea todo el html y si es algunas de las flechas entonces mueve la img con la función drawPet()
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(keyboard){
    if(keyboard.key == "ArrowUp"){
        drawPet(0,-10)
    }else if(keyboard.key == "ArrowRight"){
        drawPet(10,0)
    }else if(keyboard.key == "ArrowLeft"){
        drawPet(-10,0)
    }else if(keyboard.key == "ArrowDown"){
        drawPet(0,10)
    }
                                      })
}

function drawPet(x,y){
    //Aquí se cambia la posición
    capipepo.x += x
    capipepo.y += y
    
    //Esto para borrar el canvas cada que se va a "mover" el personaje, desde x=0, y=0, hasta mapa.ancho, mapa.alto (o sea el final del liezo)
    canvas2D.clearRect(0, 0, map.width, map.height)
    
    //Aquí dibuja la img
    //Capipepo es un objeto, pero se pueden usar variables simples
    canvas2D.drawImage(
        capipepo.photoMove, //src de la img
        capipepo.x, 
        capipepo.y,
        capipepo.width, //ancho img
        capipepo.height //largo img
    )
}

//Esto se usa para cargar la función apenas se carga la página, pero se puede usar un botón o algo que lleve a la función startGame()
window.addEventListener('load', startGame)
```